# R - use group_by() and mutate() in dplyr to apply function that returns a vector the length of groups

Tags: r, dplyr

Take the following example data:

```
set.seed(1)

foo <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10, 0, 10), y=rnorm(10, 0, 10), fac = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)))
```

I want to split the dataframe "foo" by the variable "fac" into A's and B's, apply a function (mahalanobis distance) that returns a vector of the length of each subgroup, and then mutate the output back on to the original dataframe. For example:

```
auto.mahalanobis <- function(x) {
  temp <- x[, c("x", "y")]
  return(mahalanobis(temp, center = colMeans(temp, na.rm=T), cov = cov(temp, 
use="pairwise.complete.obs")))
}

foo %>% group_by(fac) %>%
  mutate(mahal = auto.mahalanobis(.))
```

Which gives an error. Obviously this procedure can be done manually by splitting the dataset, applying the function, and adding the output as a column before putting it all back together again. But there must be a more efficient way to do this (perhaps this is a misuse of dplyr?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making use of `nest` instead:

```
foo %>%
    group_by(fac) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(mahal = map(data, ~mahalanobis(
        .x,
        center = colMeans(.x, na.rm = T),
        cov = cov(.x, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")))) %>%
    unnest()
## A tibble: 10 x 4
#   fac   mahal      x       y
#   <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A     1.02   -6.26  15.1
# 2 A     0.120   1.84   3.90
# 3 A     2.81   -8.36  -6.21
# 4 A     2.84   16.0  -22.1
# 5 A     1.21    3.30  11.2
# 6 B     2.15   -8.20  -0.449
# 7 B     2.86    4.87  -0.162
# 8 B     1.23    7.38   9.44
# 9 B     0.675   5.76   8.21
#10 B     1.08   -3.05   5.94
```

Here you avoid an explicit `"x"`, `"y"` filter of the form `temp <- x[, c("x", "y")]`, as you `nest` relevant columns after grouping by `fac`. Applying `mahalanobis` is then straight-forward.

---

### Update

To respond to your comment, here is a `purrr` option. Since it's easy to loose track of what's going on, let's go step-by-step:

1. Generate sample data with one additional column.

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   foo <- data.frame(
       x = rnorm(10, 0, 10),
       y = rnorm(10, 0, 10),
       z = rnorm(10, 0, 10),
       fac = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)))
   ```
2. We now store the columns which define the subset of the data to be used for the calculation of the Mahalanobis distance in a `list`

   ```
   cols <- list(cols1 = c("x", "y"), cols2 = c("y", "z"))
   ```

   So we will calculate the Mahalanobis distance (per `fac`) for the subset of data in columns `x`+`y` and then separately for `y`+`z`. The names of `cols` will be used as the column names of the two distance vectors.
3. Now for the actual `purrr` command:

   ```
   imap_dfc(cols, ~nest(foo %>% group_by(fac), .x, .key = !!.y) %>% select(!!.y)) %>%
       mutate_all(function(lst) map(lst, ~mahalanobis(
           .x,
           center = colMeans(.x, na.rm = T),
           cov = cov(., use = "pairwise.complete.obs")))) %>%
       unnest() %>%
       bind_cols(foo, .)
   #           x           y           z fac     cols1     cols2
   #1  -6.264538  15.1178117   9.1897737   A 1.0197542 1.3608052
   #2   1.836433   3.8984324   7.8213630   A 0.1199607 1.1141352
   #3  -8.356286  -6.2124058   0.7456498   A 2.8059562 1.5099574
   #4  15.952808 -22.1469989 -19.8935170   A 2.8401953 3.0675228
   #5   3.295078  11.2493092   6.1982575   A 1.2141337 0.9475794
   #6  -8.204684  -0.4493361  -0.5612874   B 2.1517055 1.2284793
   #7   4.874291  -0.1619026  -1.5579551   B 2.8626501 1.1724828
   #8   7.383247   9.4383621 -14.7075238   B 1.2271316 2.5723023
   #9   5.757814   8.2122120  -4.7815006   B 0.6746788 0.6939081
   #10 -3.053884   5.9390132   4.1794156   B 1.0838341 2.3328276
   ```

   In short, we

   1. loop over entries in `cols`,
   2. `nest` data in `foo` per `fac` based on columns defined in `cols`,
   3. apply `mahalanobis` on the nested and grouped data generating as many distance columns with nested data as we have entries in `cols` (i.e. subsets), and
   4. finally `unnest` the distance data and column-bind it to the original `foo` data.

Comment: Good solution, thanks! Say I wanted to expand this answer to be able to run the mahalanobis function within mutate on multiple different subsets of columns whose names are stored in vectors. E.g. cols1 <- c("x", "y"); cols2 <- c("z", "z2"); cols3 <- c("w", "w2"). Could I modify within the map() function so that it reads '.x[,cols1]' ?? This doesn't work for me but I'm struggling to understand how to work with nonstandard evaluation. Ideas?

Comment: @TKraft This is getting quite tricky and needs a bit of `purrr` magic; I have updated my answer with a step-by-step example. Please take a look.

Comment: Works for sure so accepted as answer, but having alot of trouble making sense of it all. In particular I'm finding it hard to piece together how the use of ".x" and ".y" operate throughout. I see that it is part of the map function but man does this seem complicated to achieve the desired result!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do -

```
foo %>% group_by(fac) %>%
  mutate(mahal = auto.mahalanobis(data.frame(x, y)))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   fac [2]
        x       y fac   mahal
    <dbl>   <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
 1 - 6.26  15.1   A     1.02 
 2   1.84   3.90  A     0.120
 3 - 8.36 - 6.21  A     2.81 
 4  16.0  -22.1   A     2.84 
 5   3.30  11.2   A     1.21 
 6 - 8.20 - 0.449 B     2.15 
 7   4.87 - 0.162 B     2.86 
 8   7.38   9.44  B     1.23 
 9   5.76   8.21  B     0.675
10 - 3.05   5.94  B     1.08
```

You can remove `temp <- x[, c("x", "y")]` from your function and simply use `temp` instead of `x` as function argument.

Cleaned-up function -

```
auto.mahalanobis <- function(temp) {
  mahalanobis(temp,
              center = colMeans(temp, na.rm=T),
              cov = cov(temp, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
              )
}
```

Btw, great job on your first post!

Comment: Great answer, works well on the example. Any chance you could elaborate a bit on how it works (e.g. how does "data.frame(x, y)" work on the data.frames split by group_by()?. Is there a hidden select() in the background?).

Comment: Also, in my actual usage there are dozens of columns that are saved in vectors, e.g. cols <- c("x", "y"). I would like to be able to feed that into your solution, but of course I can't do data.frame(cols) because of the quotes. Is there an easy modification to enable the use of vectors of column names with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative: group_modify

There is also the way of using the `group_modify` function of `dplyr` what makes the code shorter.

## Extension 1: Select specific columns

I have used the Mahalanobis distance to identify multivariate outliers. Here it makes sense to add variable names that should be considered (This is also an answer to @TKraft). You can specify now the columns that should be by `cols=c("x","y")`

## Extension 2: Determine threshold for multivariate outliers

Moreover, the distance alone cannot be used directly to filter out possible outliers, since one needs a threshold. This threshold could be determined by the chi-square distribution, where the degrees of freedom are equal to the number of variables to be considered.

```
    auto.mahalanobis <- function(temp, cols, chisq.prob=0.95) {
        temp_sel <- temp %>% select(any_of(cols))
        temp$mah <- mahalanobis(temp_sel,
                  center = colMeans(temp_sel, na.rm=T),
                  cov = cov(temp_sel, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
                  )
        threshold <- qchisq(chisq.prob, length(cols))
        temp$mah_chisq <- temp$mah > threshold
      return(temp)}
      
      
    foo %>%
      group_by(fac) %>%
      group_modify(~ auto.mahalanobis(temp=.x, cols=c("x","y"), chisq.prob = .975))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   fac [2]
   fac       x       y   mah mah_chisq
   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
 1 A     -6.26  15.1   1.02  FALSE    
 2 A      1.84   3.90  0.120 FALSE    
 3 A     -8.36  -6.21  2.81  FALSE    
 4 A     16.0  -22.1   2.84  FALSE    
 5 A      3.30  11.2   1.21  FALSE    
 6 B     -8.20  -0.449 2.15  FALSE    
 7 B      4.87  -0.162 2.86  FALSE    
 8 B      7.38   9.44  1.23  FALSE    
 9 B      5.76   8.21  0.675 FALSE    
10 B     -3.05   5.94  1.08  FALSE
```